# How do I control when dash sends queries out on the internet for search lenses?

Tags: unity-dash, lenses, search

I like all the cool search lenses (like github and wikipedia), but I want to control if/when dash initiates an online search.  Is there a way to limit that to only when I explicitly click on that lense's icon at the bottom of the dash overlay?

Comment: Or alternatively, is there a way to disable a lens on a per-user basis (user configurable, rather than system-wide)?  That way you could have a second account that you use for your more sensitive activities, and disable search lenses only on that account.  Tried searching briefly for this, didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to hit <kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> for the *(local) Files* lens, or  <kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> for the *(local) Apps* lens.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  It probably performs better, too, since it's searching fewer lenses, so it's a good technique even without the search privacy concern.